# How to catch errors with Ngxs Websocket plugin?

Tags: websocket, angular6, ngxs

I am trying to build an application using Angular 6 + Ngxs + WebSocket. However, some how I am not able to connect with the WebSocket plugin provided by Ngxs.

In the documentation, Ngxs mentioned that we can catch the error using WebsocketMessageError action. (I hope I understood the documentation correctly)

Documentation Link: https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/plugins/web-socket

But I am trying to import this action in my Service class, then it says that Action is not available.

Here is the code of my WebSocketService class.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, Actions, ofActionDispatched } from '@ngxs/store';
import { WebsocketMessageError, ConnectWebSocket } from '@ngxs/websocket-plugin';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class WebSocketService {


  private subject: Rx.Subject<MessageEvent>;

  constructor(private store: Store, private actions$: Actions) {
    this.actions$
      .pipe(ofActionDispatched(WebsocketMessageError))
      .subscribe(({ payload }) => {
        console.log('Got action: ', payload);
      });
  }
  public connect() {
    this.store.dispatch(new ConnectWebSocket());
  }

}
```

**I am getting following error:**

> module @ngxs/websocket-plugin/ngxs-websocket-plugin"' has no exported member
> 'WebsocketMessageError'.
>
> import WebsocketMessageError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug. Please report it in the github repository:
https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues

Comment: As suggested, I have created an issue over here:https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/503

Comment: Congratulations @codesnooker on fixing the bug you reported with your first open source PR! ;-)